# Calling __global__ CUDA functions from regular C++ code

Tags: c++, cuda

I am adding a library using CUDA to a C++ project. As of now what I'm doing is to import a `.cuh` (or `.h`) header from a `.cpp` file, and a `.cu` file implements the functions in this header. But this header contains the declaration of the methods, which have the `__global__` modifier that the regular C++ compiler complains about.

So I am wondering, what is the correct way of using a static CUDA library from C++ code?

Comment: Write wrapper functions or use the driver API

Comment: That's the approach that I am using, even though now I am having another issue I'll open a separate question for. If you want elaborate the comment into an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Your know your code and your solution better than I do. Feel free to add your own answer describing your solution in sufficient detail so that someone else would find it useful. I will happily upvote it if you do

Comment: I did it, I hope it's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by creating a header with wrapper functions that are then implemented in a .cu file like this:

```
__global__
void real_foo(int number, int *out) { 
    *out = number * 2; 
}

inline int foo(int number) { 
    int* x;
    
    cudaMallocManaged(&x, sizeof(int));
    real_foo<<<1,1>>>(number, x); 
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    int y = *x;
    cudaFree(x);
    return y;
}
```

This way the externally exposed function has nothing CUDA-specific in its signature.